# How to get the context from the Proto.application state?

Tags: protocol, validation

How to get the context from **Proto.application_state** in proto_apply_operations function in (src/lib_validation/block_validation.ml) file i.e more specifically from **state** variable in the following line **let*** **state, ops_metadata = (List.fold_left_es ....** ? and how to compare two context i.e which fields of context one should compare to know whether two contexts are equal or not ?